# Determine Inno-setup command line options

Tags: command-line, inno-setup

I have a program, `mingw-get-inst-20111118.exe`

I want to do a silent install with this.


I have been using `mingw-get-inst-20111118.exe /silent` with success, but now I want to customize the install, if possible. Is there a program that will analyze this installer and show the possible parameters?

Related links

[unattended.sourceforge.net/InnoSetup_Switches_ExitCodes.html](http://unattended.sourceforge.net/InnoSetup_Switches_ExitCodes.html)

[unattended.msfn.org/unattended.xp/view/web/39](http://unattended.msfn.org/unattended.xp/view/web/39)

Comment: It looks like newer Mingw-Get-Inst releases are using a different installer without a `/silent` switch :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the developers have not added a `Components` section to the source, making it impossible for a silent, custom installation.

Compare:
[mingw.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/mingw/mingw-get-inst/mingw-get-inst.iss](http://mingw.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/mingw/mingw-get-inst/mingw-get-inst.iss)

[code.google.com/p/msysgit/source/browse/share/WinGit/install.iss](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/source/browse/share/WinGit/install.iss)

Answer (score 2):

As the install is based on InnoSetup, the standard command line parameters available are documented at http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setupcmdline.

Looking at the installer source, I don't see much in the way of configuration.  You can pass the /DIR parameter to change the default install directory.  I'm not sure what other configuration you'd want to do though.